# 3rd dropdown is based off first 2 dropdown's selections but the 3rd's state is always 1 step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-state

I have the following code:

```
const [homeSelect, setHomeSelect] = useState('Home');
const [hedgeSelect, setHedgeSelect] = useState('Hedge');
const [symbolSelect, setSymbolSelect] = useState('');
const [similarSymbols, setSimilarSymbols] = useState([]);

const handleHome = (event) => {
    setHomeSelect(event.target.value);
    exchange_change();
  };

const handleHedge = (event) => {
    setHedgeSelect(event.target.value);
    exchange_change();
};

const handleSymbol = (event) => {
    setSymbolSelect(event.target.value);
};

const exchange_change = () => {
    setSimilarSymbols([]);
    //add symbols together from selected dropdowns
    var allSymbols = response.content.symbols[homeSelect] + response.content.symbols[hedgeSelect];
    console.log(allSymbols);

    //sort the symbols
    allSymbols = allSymbols.split(",");
    var sort_arr = allSymbols.sort();
    console.log(sort_arr);

    //find duplicates
    for(var i = 0; i < sort_arr.length-1; i++)
    {
      if(sort_arr[i + 1] == sort_arr[i]) { 
        setSimilarSymbols(similarSymbols => [...similarSymbols, sort_arr[i]]);
      }
    }
  }

<FormControl dense>
    <TextField
      id="standard-select-currency"
      select
      label="Home"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={homeSelect}
      onChange={handleHome}
      SelectProps={{
        native: true,
      }}
      helperText="Please select exchange"
    >
      <option>Home</option>
      {response ? response.content.exchanges.map((option) => (
        <option value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      )) : <option>Data is loading...</option>}
    </TextField>
  </FormControl>

  <FormControl dense>
    <TextField
      id="standard-select-currency"
      select
      label="Hedge"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={hedgeSelect}
      onChange={handleHedge}
      SelectProps={{
        native: true,
      }}
      helperText="Please select exchange"
    >
      <option>Hedge</option>
      {response ? response.content.exchanges.map((option) => (
        <option value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      )) : <option>Data is loading...</option>}
    </TextField>
  </FormControl>

  <FormControl dense>
    <TextField
      id="standard-select-currency"
      select
      label="Symbols"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={symbolSelect}
      onChange={handleSymbol}
      disabled={homeSelect == 'Home' || hedgeSelect == 'Hedge'}
      SelectProps={{
        native: true,
      }}
      helperText="Please select the exchanges"
    >
      <option>Symbol</option>
      {console.log(similarSymbols.map((element) => (element)))}
      {response ? similarSymbols.map((option) => (
        <option value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      )) : <option>Data is loading...</option>}
    </TextField>
  </FormControl>
```

After `homeSelect` and `hedgeSelect` are selected, 'similarSymbols' should be populated with the according data.

The issue is, 'similarSymbols' won't populate correctly until after `homeSelect` and `hedgeSelect` are selected one more time, for ex, select one dropdown and select another dropdown, and then select one of them one more time.

It seems as if the state is 1 step behind and I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the async of the setState, also the hook.

By the time exchange_change is called, the state is not yet set and the previous values are selected.

Try a useEffect to react to chagnes made to `homeSelect` and `hedgeSelect`:

```
const [homeSelect, setHomeSelect] = useState('Home');
const [hedgeSelect, setHedgeSelect] = useState('Hedge');
const [symbolSelect, setSymbolSelect] = useState('');
const [similarSymbols, setSimilarSymbols] = useState([]);


const handleHome = (event) => {
    setHomeSelect(event.target.value);
  };

const handleHedge = (event) => {
    setHedgeSelect(event.target.value);
};

const handleSymbol = (event) => {
    setSymbolSelect(event.target.value);
};
React.useEffect(exchange_change, [homeSelect, hedgeSelect]) // Here you listen to changes and update similarSymbols once changes are made.

const exchange_change = () => {
    setSimilarSymbols([]);
    //add symbols together from selected dropdowns
    var allSymbols = response.content.symbols[homeSelect] + response.content.symbols[hedgeSelect];
    console.log(allSymbols);

    //sort the symbols
    allSymbols = allSymbols.split(",");
    var sort_arr = allSymbols.sort();
    console.log(sort_arr);

    //find duplicates
    for(var i = 0; i < sort_arr.length-1; i++)
    {
      if(sort_arr[i + 1] == sort_arr[i]) { 
        setSimilarSymbols(similarSymbols => [...similarSymbols, sort_arr[i]]);
      }
    }
  }

<FormControl dense>
    <TextField
      id="standard-select-currency"
      select
      label="Home"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={homeSelect}
      onChange={handleHome}
      SelectProps={{
        native: true,
      }}
      helperText="Please select exchange"
    >
      <option>Home</option>
      {response ? response.content.exchanges.map((option) => (
        <option value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      )) : <option>Data is loading...</option>}
    </TextField>
  </FormControl>

  <FormControl dense>
    <TextField
      id="standard-select-currency"
      select
      label="Hedge"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={hedgeSelect}
      onChange={handleHedge}
      SelectProps={{
        native: true,
      }}
      helperText="Please select exchange"
    >
      <option>Hedge</option>
      {response ? response.content.exchanges.map((option) => (
        <option value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      )) : <option>Data is loading...</option>}
    </TextField>
  </FormControl>

  <FormControl dense>
    <TextField
      id="standard-select-currency"
      select
      label="Symbols"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={symbolSelect}
      onChange={handleSymbol}
      disabled={homeSelect == 'Home' || hedgeSelect == 'Hedge'}
      SelectProps={{
        native: true,
      }}
      helperText="Please select the exchanges"
    >
      <option>Symbol</option>
      {console.log(similarSymbols.map((element) => (element)))}
      {response ? similarSymbols.map((option) => (
        <option value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      )) : <option>Data is loading...</option>}
    </TextField>
  </FormControl>
```